# How can you check to see if a file exists (on the remote server) in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby, file, capistrano, exists

Like many others I've seen in the Googleverse, I fell victim to the `File.exists?` trap, which of course checks your *local* file system, not the server you are deploying to.

I found one result that used a shell hack like:

```
if [[ -d #{shared_path}/images ]]; then ...
```

but that doesn't sit well with me, unless it were wrapped nicely in a Ruby method.

Has anybody solved this elegantly?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

@knocte is correct that `capture` is problematic because normally everyone targets deployments to more than one host (and capture only gets the output from the first one).  In order to check across all hosts, you'll need to use [`invoke_command`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/23452d6390d2ff59240f71966409850a7646320f/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/invocation.rb#L86) instead (which is what `capture` uses internally).  Here is an example where I check to ensure a file exists across *all* matched servers:

```
def remote_file_exists?(path)
  results = []

  invoke_command("if [ -e '#{path}' ]; then echo -n 'true'; fi") do |ch, stream, out|
    results << (out == 'true')
  end

  results.all?
end
```

Note that `invoke_command` uses `run` by default -- check out the [options you can pass](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/23452d6390d2ff59240f71966409850a7646320f/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/invocation.rb#L92-148) for more control.

Comment: everyone, please upvote this and downvote the highly-voted answer, there cannot be such a huge mistake in stackoverflow!

Comment: isn't your final condition going to fail if you have more than on target? the results array could be [true, true, true]. i think you want to be using "results.all?" instead.

Comment: @TeflonTed -- yes you're correct.  I updated the answer to reflect this change. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that you ought to be doing `echo -n 'false';` in the `else` case...

Comment: I agree with @RichardCook, without an else branch, results is empty and `[].all?` is false. On my system you only enter the invoke_command block of something it output.

Comment: @PeterLong: Interestingly, `[].all?` reports `true` on my system (Ruby 1.9.3). Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @RichardCook: You are correct. I have no idea how I came to that conclusion. Sorry for spreading miss information. Also, sorry about taking a month to notice.

Comment: How do I call this function? If I include it in my `deploy.rb`, I get an `undefined method 'remote_file_exists' for #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x00000003650f88> (NoMethodError)` – basically just calling like `sudo "…" if remote_file_exists? "/foo/bar"` inside a task in a namespace.

Comment: @slhck, I think you're missing the '?' at the end of the method name.  You should be able to put it anywhere in the file.

Comment: @PeterLong, same here -- [].all? == true.  I added !results.empty? to the return value to address this

Comment: As already suggestest the cmd must be fixed to "if [ -e '#{path}' ]; then echo -n 'true'; else echo -n 'false'; fi" otherwise it does not work if you have a newly added server. In my case result was [true, true, true] for 4 servers but should be [true, true, true, false].

Answer (score 62):

In capistrano 3, you can do:

```
on roles(:all) do
  if test("[ -f /path/to/my/file ]")
    # the file exists
  else
    # the file does not exist
  end
end
```

This is nice because it returns the result of the remote test back to your local ruby program and you can work in simpler shell commands.

Comment: Many thanks! I ended up with something like `unless test("[ -f " + shared_path.to_s + "/a_shared_file.txt ]" )`

Comment: Matt, can you link to the docs for `test`?  It's a hard word to search for.  Thanks!

Comment: FAQ Example: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-check-for-existing-remote-file/

Comment: note that within context is not going to work here, so you'll need to test with absolute path. in case you want to check for directory existence, use `[ -p ... ]`

Answer (score 20):

Inspired by @bhups response, with tests:

```
def remote_file_exists?(full_path)
  'true' ==  capture("if [ -e #{full_path} ]; then echo 'true'; fi").strip
end

namespace :remote do
  namespace :file do
    desc "test existence of missing file"
    task :missing do
      if remote_file_exists?('/dev/mull')
        raise "It's there!?"
      end
    end

    desc "test existence of present file"
    task :exists do
      unless remote_file_exists?('/dev/null')
        raise "It's missing!?"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: PEOPLE! capture() function only retrieves data from the first server, so please don't base any logic on this!! capistrano is multi-server

Comment: @knocte -- thanks for pointing that out, I was able to come up with a solution that works across all matched servers.  See my answer below.

Comment: COOL!! everyone please downvote this response and upvote Patrick's!!! this is a complete failure

Answer (score 5):

May be you want to do is:

```
isFileExist = 'if [ -d #{dir_path} ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi'.strip
puts "File exist" if isFileExist == "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming you mean to wrap that with the "capture" method? http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capture

Comment: there is another way in ruby to capture the output: use the backticks: isFileExist = ` if [ -d #{dir_path} ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi `.strip (make sure to drop the extra spaces inside the backticks: I have added them to aid the SO displaying)

Answer (score 4):

I have done that before using the run command in capistrano (which execute a shell command on the remote server)

For example here is one capistrano task which will check if a database.yml exists in the shared/configs directory and link it if it exists.

```
  desc "link shared database.yml"
  task :link_shared_database_config do
    run "test -f #{shared_path}/configs/database.yml && ln -sf 
    #{shared_path}/configs/database.yml #{current_path}/config/database.yml || 
    echo 'no database.yml in shared/configs'"
  end
```