# Running rpush on production using capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

For running Rpush, I have written this in config/deploy.rb

```
 after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

  after :finished, :restart_rpush do

    on roles(:web) do
        within release_path do
            with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
                execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush stop -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
                execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush start -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
            end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

At the time of deployment I am getting this error :

```
DEBUG [76ef4791]    * Rpush isn't running? 
/home/dev/proteqtor/releases/20150714065629/tmp/rpush.pid does not exist.
```

Rpush is not running. What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is because, since Rpush is not running, you are getting an uncaught exception to `execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush stop -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"`. I.e. why run `rpush stop` if it isn't running?

Instead, first test (using Capistrano 3's [test command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20876350)) whether the pid file exists at the given path and only run stop if it, does and otherwise just run start:

```
desc 'Restart rpush'
task :restart_rpush do
  on roles(:web) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        if test('[ -f /path/to/my/pid/file ]')
          # Rpush is running
          execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush stop -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
          execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush start -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
        else
          # Rpush is not running
          execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush start -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

after :finished, :restart_rpush
```